# Terminal App not found

Tags: applications, default-applications

I am new to Lineage but not new to Linux. I am running on a raspberry pi. How do I find the AppDrawer? How do I find the terminal App. Many thanks

Comment: Based on my personal experience for LineageOS on Nexus 5, LineageOS has an in-built Terminal app, but it should be enabled first from Developer options under the name "Local terminal".

Comment: Please keep in mind that Android may be Linux based it is not a Linux system you have worked before. The whole user-system and also the UI-system is totally different from any Linux distribution I know. Therefore I recommend to you to not see Android as a Linux system but as a new system unknown to you that re-uses some basic parts of Linux.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/16244 https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how LineageOS works on raspberry pi.

But on android smartphones there is no real terminal. the closest to terminal is **terminal emulator** which can be installed as usual apk ([example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm))

The AppDrawer is probably the Android **Launcher** which can be installed as apk too ([example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher))

There is also a built-in app list in **Settings - Apps** from where you can uninstall or clear data (and even start apps on older android versions), which is therefore some kind of AppDrawer too.

On Smartphones another terminal access is the Android Debug Bridge ([adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)) which is even accessible when `system_server` is crashed or restarted (assuming the initial setup is done from developer options). Most likely on raspberry pi this is already enabled (and indeed without physical display/keyboard the only way to access your device)